# Jenkinsfile won't substitute variable

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a fairly simple script, but the Jenkinsfile never substitutes the variable (`since`) and I am not sure why.
I have tried the `$since` and `${since}` syntax and each time the substitution is empty. The parameters work just fine.

```
since = ''

pipeline {
    agent any
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '5', artifactNumToKeepStr: '5'))
    }
    parameters {
        string(defaultValue: '', description: 'The service name you wish to display status', name: 'serviceName')
        choice(choices: ['swarm-group-test', 'swarm-group-prod'], description: 'Swarm environment to remove from', name: 'swarmEnv')
        string(defaultValue: '5', description: 'Number of minutes to look back in logs', name: 'numMinutes')
    }
    tools {
        nodejs "node-js-11.12.0"
    }
    stages {
        stage('Invoke Playbook') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh (script: "node -p -e \"var a = new Date(); a.setMinutes(a.getMinutes() - ${numMinutes}); a.toISOString();\"", returnStdout: true).trim()
                }
                echo "since: ${since}"
                ansiColor('xterm') {
                    sh '''
                        export ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true
                        export ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=debug
                        ansible-playbook -b -v -u jenkins playbooks/display-service-status.yml -k --extra-vars="serviceName=$serviceName swarmEnv=$swarmEnv since=$since" -i playbooks/swarm-hosts
                    '''
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
since: 2019-09-30T12:43:12.134Z
ansible-playbook -b -v -u jenkins playbooks/display-service-status.yml -k '--extra-vars=serviceName=TEST_openam swarmEnv=swarm-group-test since=' -i playbooks/swarm-hosts
```

Comment: The downvoter, thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you cannot substitute Jenkins variables in single quote strings.

Here's a helpful document: https://gist.github.com/Faheetah/e11bd0315c34ed32e681616e41279ef4

Answer (score 0):

Relevant question. A few things to remember:

- Environment variables should be declared within an `environment` ([reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/)). They can have global or stage scope.
- Variables can also be declared with the `def` keyword in some specific locations/scopes.
- We can reference variables using groovy-like interpolation, that is, $ and curly braces inside double quote strings ([reference](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation)) .

Example:

```
environment {
    since = 'hello'
    varThatUsesAnotherVar = "${since} world"
}
stages {
    stage('Invoke Playbook') {
        steps {
            echo "since: ${since}"
            echo "varThatUsesAnotherVar : ${varThatUsesAnotherVar}"
        }
    }
}
```